# How does a space character change a number literal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

We stumbled upon this today:

```
123.toString();
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
123 .toString();
// "123"
```

Why does adding the space work? Is the number literal being coerced or cast?

I've tried some other tests to shed some light, but I can't quite understand what's going on behind-the-scenes:

```
let number = 123;
number.toString();
// "123"
Object.prototype.toString.call(123);
// "[object Number]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(123 );
// "[object Number]"
```

Comment: the dot operator can have spaces around.

Comment: My assumption is that the space allows it to be parsed as a separate token (much like parentheses would) whereas a simple `.` does not because that I would be part of the number itself in many cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first syntax, the `.` is interpreted as a decimal separator (which *must* be adjacent to the digits). In that case `toString` is unexpected, and represents a syntax error.

The property-dot does *not* have to be adjacent to the object it follows. Spacing is always allowed. So when you have the space, there is no ambiguity anymore, and the dot can be correctly interpreted.

Another variant is to *double* the dot:

```
123..toString()
```

Here the first dot is the decimal separator, but without digits following it (that is a valid syntax for a number). The second dot is then again the property-dot.

Or also:

```
(123).toString()
123.0.toString()
```

As long as you can make sure that the dot of `.toString()` cannot be interpreted as a part of the number literal, it will work as you intended.

And when you access a property of a primitive, the primitive is boxed into a wrapper object on-the-fly, so that you actually do this:

```
Number(123).toString()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that some minifiers may not pick up on this intended usage. We recently had a situation where our Vite builds were outputting `(1 .toString)`, but CloudFlare's Auto Minify feature was stripping the space in between. If you run into any token errors in your production bundle served over CloudFlare, be wary of that!

Answer (score 1):

It's not about type conversion, coercion nor anything like that. You get SyntaxError because dot after the number is understood, syntactically, as a float number. `toString` is not a valid part of float number syntax. Adding space allows parses to understand that you provided number and you want to call a method on the object.